# Looping through a dynamic List of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to implement a snippet where we can loop through a dynamic list of objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var l = new List<int>();
        l.Add(1);
        l.Add(2);
        l.Add(3);
        l.Add(4);

    foreach(var i in l){
        Console.WriteLine(i);   
        if(i==3){
            l.Add(5);
        }

    }

}

}
```

This is throwing below run time error.

```
1
2
3
Run-time exception (line 15): Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Stack Trace:

[System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.]
  at Program.Main(): line 15
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by replacing `foreach` with `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(l[i]);
     if (l[i] == 3)
     {
        l.Add(5);
     }
}
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f6gawa

Comment: I think you need to have `if(l[i] == 3)` to keep the same meaning as the OP.

Comment: I missed it @StriplingWarrior. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you  @StriplingWarrior and Reddy